# перевести число в двоичную систему

Tags: c#

у меня такая проблема: есть задача,  перевести число  в Двоичную систему... Но Нельзя использовать  НЕ конверт, НЕ массивы  НЕ лист. и.т.д и ДАЖЕ СТРИНГ Нельзя сильно трогать потому что его тоже ещё  НЕ проходили.... есть идеи как это сделать?  я попробовал, дошел до конца, записал данные в стринг   и число 16--> (00001) и теперь НЕ могу его перезаписать; так--> (10000) ну чтобы закончить, есть идеи как это сделать?
если есть  другие способы это провернуть НЕ затронув Стринг, буду рад, если нету то может хотя бы со стрингом чем поможете? только опят же минимальными операциями со Стрингом`

---

Не поверите, но рекурсию тоже нельзя использовать :(

Comment: Так как же вам помочь со стрингом, если его трогать нельзя, особенно сильно?  Вопрос не сильно понятен, так как все числа (особенно целые) в компьютере и так используют двоичную систему.  Или вам нужно десятичное число 16 конвертировать в десятичное же число 10000, которое будет "представлять" двоичную систему?

Comment: Ну а нельзя както без стринга?

Comment: Без стринга значит в цикле?  Или циклы тоже запрещены?

Comment: Не, нее :) циклы можно :)

Comment: Найдите алгоритм, в котором число разбивается на отдельные разряды при помощи деления и оператора `%`, только в таком алгоритме как правило делят на 10, так как ищут десятичные разряды, вам надо будет делить на *что-то другое*.  Также для этого используется цикл `while`

Comment: Ну ч както так и сделал, 16-->(00001) и тепер как из етого 00001 сделать 10000 не знаю... Можете помочь? Дедлайн уже через полтора часа :(

Comment: Просто на компьютере у меня стековерфлов отображается не корректно и не могу прикрепить мой недоделанный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения с циклом `while` и числом

```cs
static int toBin(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    int p = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        res += p * (n % 2);
        n >>= 1; // то же самое что n /= 2;
        p *= 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Вариант со стрингом и циклом `for`

```cs
static String toBinString(int n) {
    String res = "";
    for (; n > 0; n >>= 1) {
        res = n % 2 + res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

```
static void Main() {
    Console.Write(toBin(16));
    Console.Write(toBinString(19));
}
```

```
10000
10011
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное